# AVAudioSession option change does not take effect

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avaudiosession

My iOS app plays audio from a URL. Most of the time, I want this audio to not mix with other audio played on the device.

But sometimes, I do want to allow the audio to mix with other audio on the device.

When I initially start my audio, it works as desired; it does not mix with other audio on the device (i.e. playing music on Spotify will stop my audio from playing). Here's what I call in that case:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
```

Then when I call the following code, it successfully allows my audio to mix with others as desired:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

However, when I try to change it back to not mix with others it does not work; other audio from the device is playing along with my audio. I am calling this again just as I did initially:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
```

Any idea why I cannot change the AVAudioSession back to not mixing with others?

Comment: Have you tried passing an empty array of options?

Comment: Use the same AVAudioSession.sharedInstance() .

Answer (score 2):

I appear to have fixed this by calling the following for audio I do not want mixed / playable with other device audio playback:

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

And calling this for audio I do want mixed:

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: @RhythmicFistman SO won't allow me to accept it until tomorrow.